# Как называется человек, играющий на бубне?

Tags: терминология

Помню, этот вопрос обыграли даже в КВН. Там бубнист (подразумевался музыкант, играющий на бубне) пришел и начал бубнить)) А как действительно называется тот, кто играет на бубне (а не бубнит)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перкуссионист. Единственная оговорка: так называется человек, играющий на всех народных ударных, "б**у**бенной" специализации у него нет.
В неофициальной речи можно ещё услышать б**У**бенщик.

Гм, оказывается, есть у Даля:

> Бубенщик м. бьющий в бубны.

http://www.slova.ru/article/2205.html

Comment: Мне "бубенщик" тоже больше нравится

Answer (score 1):

**Бубнист** и называется. Бубнить (говорить нечленораздельно) и бубен в современном виде не более чем паронимы.